# Buttons csv/excel doesn't download the file instead it opens up a blank page

Tags: r, shiny, download

The buttons csv/excel opens up a blank page rather than downloading a file with a dataframe. The content of the dataframe rv1() needs to be downloaded. Could someone please tell me if something is wrong or missing?

```
server <- function(input, output) {

  rv <- reactiveValues(fli = data.frame("FlightName" = character(), "AddedValue" = character()))

  observeEvent(input$go, {
    # Bind new row to rv$fli
    rv$fli <- rbind(
      rv$fli, 
      if (input$addedvalue == "Yes"){
        data.frame("Account"=input$account,"Advertiser"= input$advertiser,"Insertion Order ID"=input$insertionorderid,"Campaign Name"=input$campaignname, "FlightName"=paste0(input$advertiser," - ",input$flightname," - ","Added Value"), "AddedValue"=input$addedvalue)}
      else{
        data.frame("Account"=input$account,"Advertiser"= input$advertiser,"Insertion Order ID"=input$insertionorderid,"Campaign Name"=input$campaignname,"FlightName"=paste0(input$advertiser," - ",input$flightname), "AddedValue"=input$addedvalue)}
    )
  })

  rv1 <- reactive({rv$fli})

  output$mytable1  <- DT::renderDataTable(
    DT::datatable(
      rv1(),
      extensions = 'Buttons',
      options = list(
        paging = TRUE,
        searching = TRUE,
        fixedColumns = TRUE,
        autoWidth = TRUE,
        ordering = TRUE,
        dom = 'tB',
        buttons = c('copy', 'csv', 'excel')
      ),
      class = "display"
    ))
}
shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

The downloaded file should have a dataframe.

Comment: When you do `rbind(df1, df2)`, the two dataframes `df1` and `df2` must have the same column names, in the same order. I suspect this is the problem. Please provide the UI if you need more help.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Somehow the same code worked in another machine. I have posted another question. Any help on that would be much appreciated. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56595027/the-two-reactive-dataframes-are-dynamic-but-the-output-is-getting-merged)