# The two reactive dataframes are dynamic. But the output is getting merged

Tags: r, dynamic, shiny, output

The outputs (2 dataframes) are getting merged. Since the dataframe is dynamic, I am expecting the output to be displayed one after the other. (Flights and Tactics are tabpanels)

```
ui <- fluidPage( 
  fluidRow(
    column(3, wellPanel(
      textInput("account","Enter the Account Name",""),
      tags$hr(),
      actionButton("goButton", "Go")
    )),
    mainPanel(
        tabsetPanel(
          tabPanel("Flight",            
                   textInput("flightname","Enter the flight Name","")
                   tags$hr(),
                   actionButton("go", "Go")),
          tabPanel("Tactic", 
                   textInput("tacticname","Enter the tactic Name",""),
                   tags$hr(),
                   actionButton("go1", "Go"))
        ),
      column(3,dataTableOutput('mytable1')),
      conditionalPanel(
        condition = "input.go1 != 0",
        column(3,dataTableOutput('mytable2')))
     )
  ))
server <- function(input, output) {
rv <- reactiveValues(fli = data.frame("FlightName" = character(), "AddedValue" = character()))

  observeEvent(input$go, {
    # Bind new row to rv$fli
    rv$fli <- rbind(
      rv$fli, 
        data.frame("Account"=input$account"FlightName"=input$flightname)
    )
  })

  rv1 <- reactive({rv$fli})

  output$mytable1  <- DT::renderDataTable(
    DT::datatable(
      rv1(),
      extensions = 'Buttons',
      options = list(
        paging = TRUE,
        dom = 'tB',
        buttons = c('copy', 'csv', 'excel','pdf')
      ),
      class = "display"
    ))

  rv <- reactiveValues(tact = data.frame("TacticName" = character()))

  observeEvent(input$go1, {
    rv$tact <- rbind(
      rv$tact, 
      data.frame("Account"=input$account,"TacticName"=input$tacticname))
  })

  rvt <- reactive({rv$tact})
}}
```

Using the similar DT::renderDataTable to display rvt(). In the ui part, I am using column(3,dataTableOutput('mytable1')) and column(3,dataTableOutput('mytable2')).

Comment: Is it possible to make a minimal working example with some fake data, with the UI component added? When you say "merged" do you mean they overlap in the UI or the two data.frames have merged together ie the function `merge`?

Comment: I have added the same ui code above. Thanks for your help.

Comment: `tags` not found. I'd try posting a new question, but make sure all the code snippets run in a fresh R session, with library commands etc. If the problem isn't re-producible people won't answer and unfortunately as so many questions get raised the question gets buried within an hour or two. I find if I have a block of code and only one part is the problem, I try to create a smaller script that only highlights the problem. It's easier to debug and more likely to get advice back